# Elasticsearch spring boot error: failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, geolocation

I get this error when i call nearest3 function. Can you help? I am trying to get nearest 3 locations in the database according to given request data parametre for example : {
"lat": 51.53266860674158,
"lon": -0.1593017578125
}

Function:

```
    @PostMapping("/nearest3")
    List<ResultData> nearest3(@RequestBody RequestData requestData) {

        GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint(requestData.getLat(), requestData.getLon());
        Sort sort = Sort.by(new GeoDistanceOrder("location", location).withUnit("km"));

        List<SearchHit<FoodPOI>> searchHits;

        if (StringUtils.hasText(requestData.getName())) {
            searchHits = repository.searchTop3ByName(requestData.getName(), sort);
        } else {
            searchHits = repository.searchTop3By(sort);
        }

        return toResultData(searchHits);
    }
```

Error:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:496) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:407) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:437) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:407) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:437) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:603) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:169) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1793) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1770) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1527) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:970) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.lambda$count$9(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:263) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:359) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.count(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:263) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:102) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186
```

Comment: can you check whether you have defined the "location" field in your document and its type and if yes can you check whether it is present in all the documents or is it in missing in some of them

Comment: Can you please add index mapping as well for your index. you can get index mapping with `GET index_name` command from kibana.